# How do I write a "pointer to const" type trait?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, type-traits, c++17

I'm looking for the following results:

```
/* true */  std::cout << ptr_to_const_v<const int*> << '\n';
/* true */  std::cout << ptr_to_const_v<const int*const> << '\n';
/* false */ std::cout << ptr_to_const_v<int*> << '\n';
/* false */ std::cout << ptr_to_const_v<int*const> << '\n';
```

Here is my attempt at a type trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_to_const : std::is_const<std::remove_pointer<T>> {};
```

This gives all **false**.

Alternatively,

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_to_const : std::is_const<const std::remove_pointer<T>> {};
```

This gives all **true**.

I suppose this is because const is a qualifier of the type, and not part of the type itself.
What can I do?

Comment: What do you expect to get from `ptr_to_const<char>::value` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking the type of the `std::remove_pointer` type trait, not the type with that trait applied.

C++14:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_to_const : std::is_const<std::remove_pointer_t<T>> {};
                                                       ^^
```

Older:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_to_const : std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type> {};
                                    ^^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^
```

However, since you simply remove the pointer, you cannot tell whether `T` was originally a pointer or not, making the trait too permissive. Since you labelled this C++1z, you can use `std::conjunction`, which is basically a short-circuiting metaprogramming `&&`:

```
template <typename T>
struct ptr_to_const : std::conjunction<
    std::is_pointer<T>, 
    std::is_const<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>
> {};
```

You could also opt for a C++1z `bool_constant` and use `&&`, although this does not do short-circuiting.

Comment: Note that this will be true also for const types which are not pointers, since `std::remove_pointer<T>` produces `T` if `T` is not a pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I just noticed that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
using ptr_to_const = std::conjunction<std::is_pointer<T>, 
                                      std::is_const<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>;
```